# Why is javascript async function not awaiting for firebase.auth method to finish?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, firebase-authentication

I am trying to check if a user is logged in and return true or false based on that. But the function return before the firebase call is completed.

```
async function checkLogin() {
    var result;

    await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          result = true;
          console.log("user is signed in");
        } else {
        result = false;
          console.log("user is not signed in");
        }
        });
        console.log("End of function");
        return result;
}
```

**"End of function"** gets printed out before any of the above two. The value in result is always undefined. It seems the function returns before the completion of `firebase.auth()`. Is there a way I can make it wait before returning.

Comment: If your end goal is checking if the user's login status, you can just use `firebase.auth().currentUser`

Comment: Does `onAuthStateChanged` actually return a promise? It seems odd to return a promise *and* take a callback.

Comment: @frunkad doesn't work either. it never waits for await. Returns undefined

Comment: In that scenario, your checkLogin() function (better: it's functionality) should be called from within onAuthStateChanged

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think so

Comment: Then why do you expect awaiting it to help?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So what are my options here?

Comment: Wrap it in a promise you *can* await or move the code you want to run after it finishes *into the callback*. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[onAuthStateChanged()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) does not return a promise, it returns an unsubscribe function.  You use `onAuthStateChanged()` to add a listener/observer/subscriber that get invoked as the sign-in state changes over time.  You can write code inside that callback to do what you want as the user become signed in or out.  Promises won't help you here - design your code to use that callback instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Doug mentioned, `onAuthStateChanged()` does not return a promise but an event, you can rather change your logic to:

```
async function afterLoginTask() {
    var result;
    // perform UI or other changes
    return result;
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("user is signed in");
      afterLoginTask()
    } else {
      console.log("user is not signed in");
    }
});
```